# create subdomains only through a php file?

Tags: php, subdomain

wo, is there a way to create subdomains only through a php file ?

like create a function call createsubdomain($username) or something?

that would really be helpful in the sense that as soon as a user registers himself on a website, he gets to access hisname.thewebsite.com to access his full profile

thanks for replues

equatorlounge.wordpress.com

Comment: That depends totally on your web server setup

Comment: off-topic, better fit to server fault but not in this form, voting to close

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042301/create-subdomains-only-through-a-php-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)

Comment: @Svisstack the question is not about recursion ;)

Comment: http://www.sf.net/projects/lightphpedit

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: +1 You managed to find a great answer for a terribly vague question :)

Comment: Should have been a comment (or even better a closevote (for which you dont have the reputation yet, but anyway))